# How to retrieve integers from the same column of SQLite DB and add to each other?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, integer

I know it's dumb, but I can't figure it out. I have a table in DB with price column and I need to provide overall price by adding integers in this column to each other. How can I do that? I've tried to make List but I dunno how to make them separate integers to add them.

Comment: can't you make a loop and add all elements of list

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL query? In that case, it would be something like `SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = '01'`. If you are looking to implement this in Android, the implement it in the same way as you execute any other SQL query. :)